# Detect the difference b/w ages greater than some value using SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to detect groups which contain the difference between first age and second age are greater than 5. For example, if I have the following data, the difference between age in `grp=1` is 39 so I want to output that group in a separate data set. Same goes for grp 4.

```
id  grp age sex
1   1   60  M
2   1   21  M
3   2   30  M
4   2   25  F
5   3   45  F
6   3   30  F
7   3   18  M
8   4   32  M
9   4   18  M
10  4   16  M
```

My initial idea was to sort them by `grp` and then get the absolute value between ages using something like `if first.grp then do;`. But I don't know how to get the absolute value between first age and second age by group or actually I don't know how should I start this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you interested in the difference between the 1st and 2nd ages per group or the 1st and last ages per group?

Comment: Also to clarify, if any two consecutive ages (in a group) are more than 5 then the whole group is captured? Is the id order important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way that I think works.

```
data have;
 input id $ grp $ age sex $;
 datalines;
1   1   60  M
2   1   21  M
3   2   30  M
4   2   25  F
5   3   45  F
6   3   30  F
7   3   18  M
8   4   32  M
9   4   18  M
10  4   16  M
;

proc sort data=have ;
 by grp descending age;
run;

data temp(keep=grp);
 retain old;
 set have;
 by grp descending age;
 if first.grp then old=age;
 if last.grp then do;
  diff=old-age;
  if diff>5 then output ;
 end;
run;

Data want;
 merge temp(in=a) have(in=b);
 by grp ;
 if a and b;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use PROC TRANSPOSE so the values in each group can easily be compared. For example:

```
data groups1;

 input id $ grp age sex $;
 datalines;
1   1   60  M
2   1   21  M
3   2   30  M
4   2   25  F
5   3   45  F
6   3   30  F
7   3   18  M
8   4   32  M
9   4   18  M
10  4   16  M
;
run;

proc sort data=groups1;
  by grp; /* This maintains age order */
run;

proc transpose data=groups1 out=groups2;
  by grp;
  var age;
run;
```

With the transposed data you can do whatever comparison you like (I can't tell from your question what exactly you want, so I just compare first two ages):

```
/* With all ages of a particular group in a single row, it is easy to compare */
data outgroups1(keep=grp);
  set groups2;
  if abs(col1-col2)>5 then output;
run;
```

In this instance this would be my preferred method for creating a separate data set for each group that satisfies whatever condition is applied (generate and include code dynamically):

```
/* A separate data set per GRP value in OUTGROUPS1 */
filename dynacode catalog "work.dynacode.mycode.source";
data _null_;
  set outgroups1;
  file dynacode;
  put "data grp" grp ";";
  put "  set groups1(where=(grp=" grp "));";
  put "run;" /;
run;

%inc dynacode;
```

Comment: Beg to disagree, but PROC TRANSPOSE should not be used for these kind of problems at all. You never know how many records will there be by group and you may end up with a lot of columns. The solution should be reasonably generic, and not dependent on a sample dataset. The solution by @CarolinaJay65 using RETAIN is the best option IMO.

Comment: You are right that the number of columns created would vary, but I think that is exactly why Proc Transpose is a good solution. It gets all the columns..the variability of the number of columns can be overcome with an array (____character____ or ____numeric____)

Answer (score 0):

If you are after the difference between just the 1st and 2nd ages, then the following code is a fairly straightforward way of extracting these.  It reads though the dataset to identify the groups, then uses the direct access method, POINT=, to extract the relevant records. I put in an extra condition, grp=lag(grp) just in case you have any groups with only 1 record.

```
data want;
set have;
by grp;
if first.grp then do;
    num_grp=0;
    outflag=0;
    end;
outflag+ifn(lag(first.grp)=1 and grp=lag(grp) and abs(dif(age))>5,1,0) /* set flag to determine if group meets criteria */;
if not first.grp then num_grp+1; /* count number of records in group */
if last.grp and outflag=1 then do i=_n_-num_grp to _n_;
    set have point=i; /* extract required group records */
    drop num_grp outflag;
    output;
    end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an SQL approach (using CarolinaJay's code to create the dataset):

```
data groups1;

 input id grp age sex $;
 datalines;
1   1   60  M
2   1   21  M
3   2   30  M
4   2   25  F
5   3   45  F
6   3   30  F
7   3   18  M
8   4   32  M
9   4   18  M
10  4   16  M
;
run;

proc sql noprint;
  create table xx as
  select a.*
  from groups1 a
  where grp in (select b.grp
                from groups1 b
                join groups1 c  on c.id = b.id+1
                               and c.grp = b.grp
                               and abs(c.age - b.age) > 5
                left join groups1 d  on d.id = b.id-1
                                    and d.grp = b.grp
                where d.id eq .
               )
  ;   
quit;
```

The join on C finds all occurrences where the subsequent record in the same group has an absolute value > 5.  The join on D (and the where clause) makes sure we only consider the results from the C join if the record is the very first record in the group.

Answer (score 0):

```
data have;
input id $ grp $ age sex $;
datalines;
1   1   60  M
2   1   21  M
3   2   30  M
4   2   25  F
5   3   45  F
6   3   30  F
7   3   18  M
8   4   32  M
9   4   18  M
10  4   16  M
;

data want;
  do i = 1 by 1 until(last.grp);
    set have;
by grp notsorted;
if first.grp then cnt = 0;
cnt + 1;
    if cnt = 1 then age1 = age;
if cnt = 2 then age2 = age;
diff = sum( age1, -age2 );
  end;
 do until(last.grp);
     set have;
 by grp;
 if diff > 5 then output;
 end;
 run;
```